# Remove Priority 2 numbers using SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, mobileconnect

I have the following script, but it doesn't seem to do the operation it is intended  for. Deleting "rows" or numbers with a priority #2:

```
Platform.Load("core","1");
var MobileConnectDE = DataExtension.Init("_MobileAddress");
MobileConnectDE.Rows.Remove(["Priority"], [2]);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that a system view? _MobileAddress

Comment: If it is a system view they are read only.

Comment: I believe it is, but hoped there might be a way to delete data associated with a subscriber here - but guess there isn't any?

Comment: No that I know of . Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the _MobileAddress is a Data view, which means it is read only. This function will not work on it.